# How can I know how much memory allocated per every app running in glassfish?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3, glassfish-4.1

How can I know how much memory allocated per every app running in glassfish ?
Our glassfish application server is running on 10 GB of RAM but.  with more than 20 application running (WARs) , I need to know how much memory consumed or allocated for every application at certain time ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a profiling tool connected to your GlassFish - e.g. Netbeans, as described in detail [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/profiler-javaee.html).

Comment: This is very useful, but it did not answer my concrete question. How can I know what is the consumed amount of RAM for every project running under Glassfish at certain time on a production server ?